# Moving an eSATA drive from a Firewire enclosure to a Thunderbolt enclosure

Tags: external-disk, thunderbolt, firewire

I want to move an eSATA drive from an external Firewire enclosure to a –yet to be purchased– Thunderbolt enclosure and connect it as the same volume.

I think it should be possible since it's the same internal interface, but then again, I want to check and confirm that there won't be any surprises.

Are there any specifics for a Thunderbolt enclosure that I'd need to pay attention to, or would I generally be better advised to get one of those [Thunderbolt to Firewire adaptors](https://www.apple.com/au/shop/product/MD464ZM/A/apple-thunderbolt-to-firewire-adapter)?

Comment: I've moved internal drive to an external enclosure and while the method of connecting the drives have changed nothing on the drive or using it has changed as that is dependent solely on the drive itself. I would think that what you are doing should work just fine. The only change being the Thunderbolt enclosure should be faster.